# HDMI cable randomly stops producing picture

Tags: hdmi, multiple-monitors, intel

I have an 24" HPes which I'm trying to connect to my Acer Aspire e5-575g(e15). The monitor worked fine for a couple of weeks, but sometimes would stop projecting picture. By this I mean that on an extended display I am able to access the desktop space, but the monitor is dark. It stopped working completely last night and I'm unsure why, as the cable and the monitor connect perfectly fine with my work laptop.

I have Windows 10 and the HDMI port uses the integrated graphics card of my i5-6200U(Intel(R) HD 520), its drivers are up to date.

Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Comment: Please replace the cable, which is the most likely point of failure.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the monitor power cable and HDMI cable are securely plugged in. If the issue still occurs the cable is probably bad, replace it and see if that works. If that doesn't fix it, either the HDMI port on the monitor is bad, or the HDMI port is bad in the GPU. The ports shouldn't have gone bad after a maximum of a month of usage though.